# Can we Connect directly the Azure Event Hub With Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure

I have sent message to Azure Event Hub through C# Application.

After I send the message to Event Hub ,it will be given as input to the Azure Stream analytics and Process some Events and sent back to Event Hub as an output of Azure Stream Analytics.

Now I want to sent the Notification to the Mobile App through Notification Hub of Azure after receiving the Event hub's Output.

How can I connect azure event hub and notification hub now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I figured out:
Azure Event Hubs is built on Service Bus.
You can connect to a topic/queue to retrieve messages, using the pump model (event driving instead of polling).

So you would have to write your own code to take the message out of the second Event Hub (which is the output of Stream Analytics) and create a notification on the Notification Hub. This could run in a Web Job.